# Histogram comparison as "neuronal-networks for the poor"

Tags: opencv, pattern-matching

I'm learning pattern recognition with OpenCV and want to implement a classifier.

As I've understood it, the usual approach is implementing neuronal network evaluation on all input values and outputting a decision. Now, I'm afraid, learning NN would outrun my mental ability, and I am looking for an easier way.

My question is, is it possible to create a histogram of input values, where X is a feature class and Y is its value and make the decision using simple histogram comparison? (I don't mean like the color histograms.)

Did anyone already apply such a method? If so, how accurate were the results?

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are proposing is is indeed very similar to a single layer neural network ([single layer perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) / [linear classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier)). Let's say you have N features in your image. Your neural network would then have N inputs where the value of the input could be the number of times a feature occurs or the value/strength of the feature.

If you have only two classes A and B you would have one output node. Each input is connected to the output with a weight. The output is then the sum of all weighted outputs. If the output is above some threshold, your data can be classified with class A otherwise it is class B. In order to correctly classify your data, you will have to modify the weights in the network (this is called "training").

If you want to have more classes, you could add more output nodes. However, you will have then the case that some data can be classified as multiple classes. Moreover, your network will always be a linear function approximator. By adding a layer in between, your network will become much more powerful!

Basic neural networks are easy. I suggest you spend some more time reading about it on Wikipedia.

Comment: +1: Thank you for the explanation and the links! I'll try to understand NN.   P.S.: just started reading http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Classification-2nd-Richard-Duda/dp/0471056693 and liked it instantly.